# (Windows) How to route outgoing SSL to a different IP?

Tags: networking, routing, ssl

```
netsh interface portproxy add v4tov4 listenport=443 connectport=443 connectaddress=192.168.1.18
```

I'm trying to use the above command to route the traffic but it doesn't seem to be working. What i want to do is route all my SSL traffic to an IP other than default gateway. How can this be achieved?